# Convert an existing HTTP Project into HTTPS in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have had several occasions where I built a ASP.Net Core Web API project for http only, then realized that I needed HTTPS.  (I sometimes build for http only because our load balancer does https termination for me.)

But each time I try to convert an http project to an https project it always fails.  Usually not able to load on the https port I pick.

Is there a process to convert an existing http Web API project to an http**s** one?  Specifically on how to get a SSL port that will work?

(Note: I am using .Net 6 incase it matters.)

Comment: What is the specific error message? Is there any http URL inside your project? I didn't see any error with just simply modify the debug settings to https.